# In Rust, I've created an impl return type, which I can pass as a parameter. But I'm not finding a way to store it in my Struct?

Tags: rust, closures

I've thinned this down and changed to a channel, so that it might make more sense. I'd like to store an `impl` which is a predicate function, in my `Struct`, the code follows...

Start with a simple function that returns an `impl` for testing something.

```
fn make_test<T>(sender: Sender<T>) -> impl Fn()->bool {
    let closure = move|| {sender.is_full()};
    closure
}

struct MyStruct <T> {
    sender: Sender<T>,
    parker: Arc<Mutex<MyParker>>,
}
impl<T> MyStruct<T> {
    fn something(&self) {
```

Here we are creating it and passing it as a `parameter`.

```
        let test = make_test(self.sender.clone());
        &self.parker.lock().unwrap().parked(test);
    }
}


struct MyParker {
    test: impl Fn()->bool,
}
impl MyParker {
    fn parked(&mut self, test: impl Fn()->bool) {
```

The `parameter` is accepted as `test`, no issue there. But how do I declare it in the `Struct` so that I can save it for later?

```
        self.test = test;
    }
}
```

As I've currently declared it, it throws a compiler error:
error[E0562]: `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types

I'm hoping that's a result of me doing something wrong, as opposed to you can't store an `impl` in a Struct. I've tried: `Arc<>`, `Box<>`, all to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

"an `impl`" is **not a type.** It's, more or less, syntactic sugar for an unnamed type (in return value position) or type parameter (in argument position).

1. ```
   fn make_test<T>(sender: Sender<T>) -> impl Fn()->bool {
   ```

   In the return position, it means "there is a specific concrete type, but I'm not writing it out, and it might change, but it will definitely implement `Fn() -> bool`". It is needed to *return* bare closures, which have otherwise unnameable types. (If the type of a closure could be written, it would have to specify the types of all the closed-over values.)
2. ```
   fn parked(&mut self, test: impl Fn()->bool) {
   ```

   This is pure sugar for

   ```
   fn parked<T: impl Fn()->bool>(&mut self, test: T) {
   ```

   That is, `parked` is a generic function.

Therefore, you cannot *just* have a struct field of type `impl ...`, because it isn't a concrete type. What you can do are the same things as any other time you have more than one type: you can write a struct with a type parameter,

```
struct MyParker<F: Fn() -> bool + 'static> {
    test: F,
}
```

but that won't work because you can't constrain things to the unknown closure type — or you can write a struct that contains a `dyn` value.

```
struct MyParker {
    test: Box<dyn Fn() -> bool + 'static>,
}
impl MyParker {
    fn parked(&mut self, test: impl Fn() -> bool + 'static) {
        self.test = Box::new(test);
    }
}
```

Note that in order to store the `Fn` we need to provide a lifetime bound. I've written it as `'static` here, but you can also use a lifetime parameter.

But if you want to avoid the cost of `dyn`amic dispatch, you're better off replacing your closure with an explicitly defined struct and method — or, if applicable (I haven't looked at what you're actually trying to do), just making `MyParker` be that struct so that it has a field of type `Sender<T>`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Armed with that information, I decided that I can contain the information necessary within a struct and hand that back, hopefully as a trait object which can hide the details while at the same time exposing the test method. It should also be able to manage lifetime semantics.